# Visual Studio 2017, "Introduce local for 'this'"

Tags: visual-studio

What is the point of Visual Studio hint: Introduce local for 'this'?

I use this.Method() referencing, and I don't understand, why this proposed change could make sense. I use this/base referencing since I read it somewhere as new coding standard (replacement of _ prefixes). But VS seem to be against it.